# What is the recommended way to build Ethereum wallet ?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

What is your recommendation for building hosted Ethereum wallet, where we manage private keys.

Among other questions :

- Do we store private keys on in the DB or keep them in the node ?
- If we are storing them in the DB, do we have to import them every time client need to perform transaction, then remove them ?
- if the node is running on different server than the App, what is the best way to connect ?

This is new field, any ideas where there we can find guidance for this ?